# Higher Order Function as Enum paramter

Tags: kotlin, enums

I want to use a higher order function as enum parameter. But this doesn't work. I have the following declaration:

```
enum class Enum(val someValue: Int, val someMethod: () -> Unit)
{
    FIRST_VALUE(0, {method0()}),
    SECOND_VALUE(1, {method1()})

    fun method0() {

    }

    fun method1() {

    }
}
```

But `method0()` and `method1()` cannot be found. Error is `Unresolved reference: method0`.

Is it somehow possible to realize this with an enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the methods inside `Enum` is `Enum.() -> Unit`, not `() -> Unit`. It will work if you change the parameter type.

Note that you can also use a method reference with `Enum::method0`, instead of creating a new lambda. It's a bit more readable.

```
enum class Enum(val someValue: Int, val someMethod: Enum.() -> Unit) {
    FIRST_VALUE(0, Enum::method0), // Using a method reference
    SECOND_VALUE(1, {method1()})

    fun method0() {

    }

    fun method1() {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Just had to add `Enum::method0`. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, but you need to move functions `method0` and `method1` out of the `Enum` class:

```
enum class Enum(val someValue: Int, val someMethod: () -> Unit)
{
    FIRST_VALUE(0, ::method0), // pass reference to the function
    SECOND_VALUE(1, { method1() }); // pass lambda and call `method1()` function in it
}

fun method0() {

}

fun method1() {

}
```

You can pass reference to a function as a lambda argument as demonstrated in `FIRST_VALUE` example, or lambda and call a function in it - demonstrated in `SECOND_VALUE` example.